# Web applications starts on port 8080, where can I change it?

Tags: glassfish-3, netbeans6.8

I have Netbeans IDE version 6.8, and Glassfish version 3.
My glassfish listener is set to port 81, but when I try to run the simplest web application via the Netbenas IDE it tries to run it on port 8080. where can I change it ? Using port 8080 for my web application is out of the question for me.

Comment: which listener is set to port 81?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late, but this should work...

I don't have 6.8 anymore, but the following is true for 6.9 and 6.10m1 - in the directory <home dir>/.netbeans/<version>/config, there is a file called .nbattrs - edit it, and look for something like:

`<attr name="GlassFishEE6\Instances\glassfish_autoregistered_instance\httpportnumber" stringvalue="8082"/>`

Change the value to whatever you've set in the appropriate Glassfish domain.  If, like me, you have more than one version of Glassfish installed, or perhaps multiple domains, just look out for the ....displayName keys and follow your nose - it should be obvious which one you're altering.

HTH,

John

NB: you can, of course, delete the server and add it in again using the wizard to select the right ports - but I think editing .nbattrs is far easier

NB2: there is another .nbattrs file further down the directory chain that also contains glassfish config (can't remember the exact location - sorry!) and this looks like the right place to change the port - but editing this file appears to have no effect as, for me, it gets overridden with whatever is in config/.nbattrs file whenever I start up Netbeans

Comment: In Nb 8, there is no .nbattrs in config

Answer (score 10):

Locate config folder which may be as follows:

```
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\config
```

Open domain.xml using any text editor.

Look for 8080 and change it to some other port number that doesn’t conflict with other port numbers.

source:
http://ohmjavaclasses.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-change-port-number-for-glassfish.html

Comment: If you don't modify .nbattrs file , Netbeans re-writes 8080 in domain.xml and GlassFish is starting at port:8080 (I am using Netbeans 7.1.2 and GlassFish 3.1.2)

Comment: @skiabox yes true but it solved my problem i dont have much time so this solution did what i wanted

Comment: Thanks oits really helps me a lot ..

can you please guide me to connect access db to netbeans

Comment: Thank you, I spent some time looking for this, it has been a long I last configured payara domains.

Answer (score 5):

If GlassFish and Oracle Database are installed in the same system, it results in port conflict as both of them use port 8080.

Here is the procedure to change port number of GlassFish so that you can run GlassFish at a different port number from Oracle to avoid the port conflict.

1. Find out the folder where GlassFish is installed.

   If you installed GlassFish along with NetBeans, you can find out the               folder where GlassFish is installed by using the following procedure.

   ```
    Select Services window by using **Window -> Services** in NetBeans IDE

    Expand **Servers** node and select GlassFish Domain

    Right click and select **Properties** option from popup menu.

   On the right of **Domains Folder** you can see the folder where GlassFish is   installed. 
   For example : 
   C:\netbeans6.8\glassfish-v3\glassfish\domains. You can also see the            other details regarding Glassfish such as port number, in the same window.
   ```
2. Go to the folder where Glassfish in installed.
3. Go into **config** folder which is as follows: **c:\netbeans6.8\glassfish-3\glassfish\domains\domain1\config**
4. Open **domain.xml** using any text editor.
5. Look for **8080** and change it to some other port number that doesn’t conflict with other port numbers. I generally change it to 9999.
6. Save domain.xml.
7. Now you need to remove GlassFish from NetBeans and add it again so that NetBeans IDE understands the new port number. For this do the following

   ```
    In **Servers** window of NetBeans, remove GlassFish by using **RemoveServer** button after selecting GlassFish server.

    Click on **AddServer** and select GlassFish V2 or GlassFish V3 and click on **Next**.

    Select the **Installation Location** of GlassFish and click on **Next**.

   Accept defaults and click on **Finish.**
   ```
8. Restart GlassFish, if it was already running.

Comment: After trying all the other answers, the only thing that worked for me was to delete the server and re-create it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late, too, but I'll add my comments just-the-same in case anyone runs across this issue in the future. I'm running Windows 7 with NetBeans 6.9.1 and GlassFish 3 locally on a different port (2118) as not to conflict with my Tomcat server on default (8080). If you navigate to `<home_dir>/.netbeans/<version>/config/GlassFishEE6/Instances`, you'll find your *.nbattrs* file.

Edit `<attr name="httpportnumber" stringvalue="8080"/>` to reflect the desired port. Save the file. Restart your server and you should be able to deploy/test your web apps, as desired, using NetBeans.

Incidentally, poking around under `<home_dir>/.netbeans/<version>/config/J2EE/InstalledServers`, you'll see another .nbattrs file and because I have two app servers installed locally, I see `<fileobject name="instance">` for Tomcat and `<fileobject name="instance_1">` for GlassFish. XML entries `<attr name="port" stringvalue="8080"/>` and `<attr name="port" stringvalue="2118"/>` reflect the respective assigned ports for each server and the change made in the previous .nbattrs file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Glassfish 3.1.1 it may in /home/user/.netbeans/7.1.2/config/GF3_1/domain1/config/domain.xml,Find the 8080 port and replace it with alternate port number.