# html project running on localhost8383 but I want it to run on 8080

Tags: html, server, port

I have a html project running on localhost:8383 but I want it to run on 8080.

Comment: What server are you using?

Comment: In netbeans I have Glassfish server. But not able to figure out why its running on 8383, please help thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622894/netbeans-starts-running-web-applications-on-port-8080-where-can-i-change-it

Comment: that was bit helpful but my problem is still there, my nodejs is running on 8080 I want my project to run on this port.

Comment: This isn't even a question... and if it were the answer would be "Run it on port 8080 instead of 8383".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All good, I found myself.
The problem was with node server port, since it was running on port 80.
Which should have superuser access, I changed the port number to 6060.
It working now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the procedure to change port number of GlassFish so that you can run GlassFish at a different port number from Oracle to avoid the port conflict.

Find out the folder where GlassFish is installed.
If you installed GlassFish along with NetBeans, you can find out the folder where GlassFish is installed by using the following procedure.

Select Services window by using Window -> Services in NetBeans IDE
Expand Servers node and select GlassFish Domain
Right click and select Properties option from popup menu
On the right of Domains Folder you can see the folder where GlassFish is installed. For example : C:\netbeans6.8\glassfish-v3\glassfish\domains You can also see the other details regarding Glassfish such as port number, in the same window.
Go to the folder where Glassfish in installed.
Go into config folder which is as follows: c:\netbeans6.8\glassfish-3\glassfish\domains\domain1\config
Open domain.xml using any text editor.
Look for 8080 and change it to some other port number that doesn’t conflict with other port numbers. I generally change it to 9999.
Save domain.xml.
Now you need to remove GlassFish from NetBeans and add it again so that NetBeans IDE understands the new port number. For this do the following:
In Servers window of NetBeans, remove GlassFish by using RemoveServer button after selecting GlassFish server
Click on AddServer and select GlassFish V2 or GlassFish V3 and click on Next
Select the Installation Location of GlassFish and click on Next
Accept defaults and click on Finish
Restart GlassFish, if it was already running.

Taken from http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/java/changeglassfishport.aspx